# Asterisk in django forms validation messages

Tags: django, forms

I use `clean_fieldname` methods in my forms to validate data.

I use `{{field.errors.as_text}}` to output errors to templates. Every error message has an asterisk ("*" symbol) at the beginning of it. Is there any way to output validation messages without asterisks?

(No, I don't include asterisks myself, i just `raise ValidationError(u'text')` from the `clean` method)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, i just had to iterate over errors and print them without as_text()

Answer (score 14):

One more way:

```
{{ form.username.errors.as_text|cut:"* " }}
```

Comment: If the error message contains `* ` (asterix+space) somewhere in between, this will remove that as well. Isn't there a template filter that removes characters from left only?

Answer (score 3):

The asterisks are added when print the field errors as_text. See [django/forms/util.py](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/forms/util.py)  ErrorList for more detail.  It is easier to customize the errors if you print them as_ul instead.  The ul will be given a class "errorlist".  The Django book has a section on customizing the form errors. Chapter 7 under "Customizing Form Design": http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter07/

Comment: +1, styling the ul with css is the approach to take. My only correction is to point to more recent documentation: http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter07/ (see Customizing form design)

Comment: i don't usually need styling, i usually need transfer errors via XML and show them to user.

Comment: That's strange, that there is no ormal documented way to get just plain text errors without asterisks.